# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot call Glide.get() in registerComponents(), use the provided Glide instance instead -- Glide Version 4.9.0

Tags: android, android-glide

Migrated from Gilde 3.7.0 to Glide 4.9.0.

Defined my MyAppGlideModule as below.

```
@GlideModule
public  class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    private static final int IMAGE_DISK_CACHE_MAX_SIZE = 250 * 1024 * 1024;

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
        builder.setDiskCache(new DiskLruCacheFactory(
            FileUtils.getCacheFile(context, false).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + GLIDE_CACHE_PATH,
            IMAGE_DISK_CACHE_MAX_SIZE));
    //        builder.setMemoryCache(new LruResourceCache(customMemoryCacheSize));
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    //        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.newBuilder().connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new TSImageRetryIntercepter(3))
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);
        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run code which is loading image as below

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageBean.getGlideUrl())
                .override(with, height)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                .dontAnimate()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.shape_default_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .error(R.drawable.shape_default_image)
                .into(view);
```

getting following error.

```
Process: com.my.package.debug, PID: 5561
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You cannot call Glide.get() in registerComponents(), use the provided Glide instance instead
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.checkAndInitializeGlide(Glide.java:180)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:168)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:689)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:716)
    at com.my.package.list.adapter.DynamicListItemForShorVideo.initVideoView(DynamicListItemForShorVideo.java:106)
    at com.my.package.list.adapter.DynamicListItemForShorVideo.convert(DynamicListItemForShorVideo.java:77)
    at com.my.package.list.adapter.DynamicListItemForShorVideo.convert(DynamicListItemForShorVideo.java:45)
    at com.my.package.recyclerview.base.ItemViewDelegateManager.convert(ItemViewDelegateManager.java:93)
    at com.my.package.recyclerview.MultiItemTypeAdapter.convert(MultiItemTypeAdapter.java:55)
    at com.my.package.recyclerview.MultiItemTypeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MultiItemTypeAdapter.java:99)
    at com.my.package.recyclerview.MultiItemTypeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MultiItemTypeAdapter.java:17)
    at com.my.package.recyclerview.wrapper.HeaderAndFooterWrapper.onBindViewHolder(HeaderAndFooterWrapper.java:76)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at com.my.package.layout.SmartRefreshLayout.onLayout(SmartRefreshLayout.java:623)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
```

Comment: I just found [this closed issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2780) that appears to be the same as yours. Apparently the error message is misleading. Can you see if the solutions from the link help you?

Comment: Sure, I will take care of this thing in future. Thanks for revision :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use GlideAppModule, from docs, you should use:

```
GlideApp.with(mContext)
```

Instead of:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
```

Comment: GlideApp is not generated, I followed the steps from https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html